# How to get the hard disk partition information QT

Tags: winapi, qt4, device, disk-partitioning

I'm trying to get system information in a QT project, I want to know the hard disk partition in Windows and the different properties of each partition.

Here is my code:

```
QString drivename=QString(FileInfo.absolutePath().at(0))+":\\\\";
    ULARGE_INTEGER freeBytesToCaller;
    ULARGE_INTEGER TotalBytes;
    ULARGE_INTEGER FreeBytes;
    freeBytesToCaller.QuadPart = 0L;
    TotalBytes.QuadPart = 0L;
    FreeBytes.QuadPart = 0L;

    if( !GetDiskFreeSpaceEx( drivename.toStdWString().c_str(), &freeBytesToCaller,&TotalBytes,&FreeBytes ) )
    {
        qDebug() <<drivename<< "ERROR: Call to GetDiskFreeSpaceEx() failed.";

    }
   // qDebug()<<"drive type of "<<drivename<<"  "<<GetDriveTypeW(drivename.toStdWString().c_str());
     int TotalBytes_gb = TotalBytes.QuadPart/(1024*1024*1024) ;
```

It lets me know the partition name (eg. C:\) the size and type but what I want also is to get information about the partition (\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1 C:\ 232GB)

How can I get the information about the partition?

Comment: if you are using GetDiskFreeSpace() it's not really a Qt question - it's a windows one

Comment: Thank you but I still want something give me partition information, any help please

Comment: Research the necessary Windows API calls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution that I think is more helpful [Displaying Volume Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542456.aspx)

thank you all any way.